# Object is possibly undefined -- but it's not...?

Tags: typescript

```
type Metadata = {
  tags?: Set<string>;
};

const metadata: Metadata = {
  tags: new Set<string>(),
};

metadata.tags.add('test'); // <-- Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

But how? I've initialized it to `new Set<string>` ... ?

I assume because it is marked as nullable/optional in `Metadata`, but I figured the compiler would see that I had indeed initialized `tags` with a value.

Comment: You asserted that its type was of `Metadata`, whose type has `tags` as optional. If you didn't want that, just remove the type notation there entirely? `const metadata = {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When TypeScript evaluates your types, it works down your code, line by line, narrowing the type of the variable as it goes.

If you used:

```
const metadata = {
  tags: new Set<string>(),
};
```

The type of this constant variable, is:

```
{
  tags: Set<string>;
}
```

However, on that same line, you tell TypeScript, "no, this object is a `Metadata` object - treat it as such" when you use:

```
const metadata: Metadata = {
  tags: new Set<string>(),
};
```

So, by the time TypeScript gets to checking this line, `metadata` is a `Metadata` object, where the `tags` property is optional:

```
metadata.tags.add('test'); // metadata.tags is possibly 'undefined'
```

Because you understand that you've just set this property, you can use the `!` type assertion to say "this value is not `undefined` or `null`".

```
metadata.tags!.add('test');
```

If you plan to initialize each property in `metadata`, you can mutate the type to say "this object follows the shape of `Metadata`, but each property is required" using the `Required<T>` utility type:

```
const metadata: Required<Metadata> = {
  tags: new Set<string>(),
};
```

Which will allow you to use your assignment as normal:

```
metadata.tags.add('test');
```

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I was hoping that by specifically setting `tags`, the type would be inferred as `Metadata & { tags: Set<string> }`. It seems like the compiler _could be_ smart enough to figure this out -- maybe in the future! Thanks.